# How to memory test in Linux?

Tags: linux

I'm planning to test my Linux box and I want to start in memory testing. But my problem is what should I need to test the memory in my linux box? Should I need a tool? Or there are some APIs to use to build some scripts?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) or something else?

Comment: What do you mean, "memory test"?

Answer (score 6):

Many live linux cds have an option to do a memory test at the boot menu, usually marked as memtest+86 or something similar. For instance, I'm pretty sure ubuntu 9.10 has it.

Comment: actually, you can probably bang a memtest entry into your grub, and save yourself a cd/flash drive/download time.

Comment: actually, you probably already have a memtest entry in your grub.  if you're on Ubuntu and you don't, `sudo aptitude install memtest86+` should install it and add it to your boot menu.