# May RAM failure made no beep?

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard, bios

Several days ago, I added some more RAM to my PC (4x2 to 4x2+2x2) from my old PC. They worked before, i never had any problem with those modules. My motherboard supports up to 16gb on 1066MHZ, and actually, my modules are 1600(4x2) and 1333(2x2), so, i know they will work all together at 1066MHZ, but, since yesterday, my PC suddenly freezes, no blue screen, everything hangs up and stop working. When i tried to run again the PC, it doesn't start, no bios beep, no post message, just all leds from HD and CD drives blink 3 times, and thats all.

First, i thought it could be a CPU/motherboard problem (both of them have 8 years, and they had worked a lot), because they made no beep. I left the PC unplugged 2 minutes, plug again, and it worked, join on the BIOS menu, and realice that my CPU was 72ºC. Open the case, unmount heat sink, clean heat sink, mount again, and it worked fine (started rendering a video so CPU would have a heavy load, it didnt went through 60ºC this time)

Today, it happened again. I was sure that it wasn't CPU overheat, because the fan wasn't making much noise, tried to wait about 2 minutes but it still not working. Then, i tried, just tried, to remove the RAM modules i added 2 weeks ago, and everything start working again.

I know that RAM failures can make a blue screen, or even some beep on bios startup, but, could it be that it made no bios beep? i never heard about no bios beep on RAM failure and i'm a bit afraid that it could be a CPU/Motherboard failure.

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: If you are running windows, you may want to run the memory diagnostics tool.  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/diagnosing-memory-problems-on-your-computer.  For linux see this post:  http://superuser.com/questions/135736/how-to-memory-test-in-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAM failure is tricky. If all the RAM modules in your system are faulty which makes the system unable to boot up, you will certainly hear beeps.

However, RAM can be faulty in many other ways which compromise your system's stability but don't show outright. It's totally normal for RAM to be faulty and not cause BIOS beep, since when the computer boots, depending on the configuration RAM can be tested very briefly or even not at all.

I've had multiple systems in the past where bad RAMs caused BSOD but there was no beep nor any other error indication from the BIOS.

Comment: Thanks, i never heard about RAM making no beep code on motherboard, but i knew that a CPU/motherboard failure could be what was making no beep.